# how can i manage database in my library management system?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

For the given topic help me for registering book for individual student  such that while issuing book   the no. of books in library database decreases and increases in student account. i have no idea to start over. i am using c# visual studio and sql server 2012 for database.

Comment: It is better to show us what you did until now

Comment: How about reading any articles about databases and vs?

Comment: i have only made two tables each for students and books. i want solution for increasing the no. of book used in student table and decreasing the no. of book in book table while issuing book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two tables is not really enough to produce a good solution. You need a table for `student`, `book`, `loan` and `inventory`. This is a crude and basic setup but it will have the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    studentId // key
    // other columns
)

CREATE TABLE book
(
    bookId // key
    // other columns
)

CREATE TABLE inventory
(
    bookId // FK
    quantity
    // other columns
)

CREATE TABLE loan
(
    loanId int // key
    studentId // FK
    bookId // FK
    // other columns
)
```

So now you can track who has book issued to them and the current number of books in the library.

Comment: thank you so much !! really gratefull to you . can you plz tell me what should i do further for granting book to student??

Comment: no problem, the way to show gratitude for an answer on Stack Exchange is to vote or tick the answer ;). For granting a book to a student there are few ways to do it. But a simple way would be to write a stored procedure which would get called when a book(s) is going to be issued. It would insert a row for EACH book that a student takes from the library in the loan table. Also it would change the inventory table by decreasing the quantity of that book(s) using an update query.